# How to add filter to excel table in UI Path?

Tags: uipath

I have an excel file with a table named 'Table1' in it. I have to perform 'Filter Table' activity in UiPath with the condition "column1 begins with '*my column'". But when I specify the value like this, the column is filtered for 'ends with' operation.
Here is the screenshot for my table-
[image]

Below is the screenshot for the steps I followed-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `*my value` as the search / filter pattern, then it'd mean, anything in the beginning and must have `my value` in the end. So, it is being interpreted correctly as `Ends With`. If you want to have a `Begins With` filter, you should have your filter text followed by the wildcard, like - `my value*`.

Further, if you want to include wildcard as a literal in the search pattern, you'd need to escape that by enclosing it in brackets like `[*]my value*` - this'd search for text beginning with `*my value`.

> MS Excel / VBA also supports **Tilde** `~` as an escape character in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered many times on [UiPath Forum](https://forum.uipath.com)
For example https://forum.uipath.com/t/filter-table-in-excel-data-tables/559/3

Answer (score 0):

In excel filters, '*' represents any series of characters.
The issue in the above case is that the filter value in the condition already contains a '*'. Because of this, system always reads it as '*My column' => '[any characters]My column'. i.e., value ends with 'My column'.
To resolve this issue, I have specified contains filter instead of Begins with as '*My column*'.

I have also tried to escape '*'. But it threw excel exception.

In addition, you can not specify condition as "Column1 Like '*My column%'". This works file when you are adding filter to 'DataTable'(after performing 'ReadRange' activity). But in this case, you will retrieve all the records and then you will be filtering the columns. This will lead to performance issues if the the excel table is huge.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the syntax below to perform filter activities in an excel:

DataTableName.Select("[ColumnName]='Datawithwhichweneedtofilter’").CopytoDataTable()